# how to fix the error message it shows 2 message at the same time

Tags: php, html

When the Username is already exist in the database and the user input the used invite code it shows 2 error message and it messed up my registration form.

How do I make the error show one at a time?
For example if the user input username that is in the db already and it inputs the used invite code it will show "Code Already Used"

**Function of form**

```
function register(){
    global $db, $errors, $username;

    $username    =  mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password  =  mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
    $inviteCode  =  mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['inviteCode']);


  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if ($user) {
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
      array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }
  }

/////////////////////////////////////////////
$rs_check = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `taken` from ic WHERE inviteCode='$inviteCode'"); 
if (0 == mysqli_num_rows($rs_check)) { 
array_push($errors, "Invalid Code");
}
else{
$token = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_check);
        if ($token['taken'] > 0) {
            array_push($errors, "Code is already used");
        } elseif (mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE ic SET taken='1' WHERE inviteCode='$inviteCode'")){
        }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);

        if (isset($_POST['user_type'])) {
            $user_type = e($_POST['user_type']);
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, user_type, password) 
                      VALUES('$username', '$user_type', '$password')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);

        }else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, user_type, password) 
                      VALUES('$username', 'user', '$password')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);

            $logged_in_user_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);

            $_SESSION['user'] = getUserById($logged_in_user_id);
            $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.php');              
        }
    }
}
```

**Function of the error message**

```
function display_error() {
    global $errors;

    if (count($errors) > 0){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible show fade">
                      <div class="alert-body">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                          <span>&times;</span>
                        </button><b><center>';
            foreach ($errors as $error){
                echo $error .'</b></center></div></div>';
            }
    }
}
```

**How i display error message in html**

```
<p><?php echo display_error(); ?></p>
```

Comment: You are pushing all the error messages to an array and then looping through them. If you only want to show the first one skip the `foreach ($errors as $error)` and just echo `$errors[0]`. If you'd rather show just the last use `echo end($errors);` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd suggest showing all error messages that relate to the users input.

1. Merge the error text
2. Display multiple alter-danger boxes.

**1. Merging the error texts**

Just merge the errors by not closing off the tags within the `foreach`.

```
function display_error() {
global $errors;

    if (count($errors) > 0){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible show fade">
                      <div class="alert-body">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                          <span>&times;</span>
                        </button><b><center>';
            foreach ($errors as $error){
                echo $error .'<br />';
            }
            echo '</b></center></div></div>';
    }
}
```

**2. Display multiple alter-danger boxes**

```
function display_error() {
    global $errors;

    if (count($errors) > 0){
            foreach ($errors as $error){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible show fade">
                      <div class="alert-body">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                          <span>&times;</span>
                        </button><b><center>' . $error .'</b></center></div></div>';
            }
    }
}
```

If you really just want one error to show, you can do the following:

```
function display_error() {
    global $errors;

    if (count($errors) > 0){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible show fade">
                      <div class="alert-body">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                          <span>&times;</span>
                        </button><b><center>' . $errors[0] .'</b></center></div></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG! thank you very much for the help i tried the last one its really suites what i need :)